# VBA to export images from PowerPoint with Section and Title as filename

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I'm currently working on a solution for a group within our business that will allow them to create slides using PowerPoint 2013 from a PowerPoint presentation at HD resolution with specific filenames that will be used as digital signage through a different system that doesn't support PowerPoint files.

I've been looking for a solution using VBA to export the files as required, but haven't quite hit the mark. I'm not a VBA programmer myself, and have done my best to compile something that is close to my needs.

Exact requirements:

- Request input from user for directory to export to
- Export slides as PNG format at 1920 x 1080 resolution
- Only export slides where the file doesn't already exist
- Filename format is `[Section Name] [Slide Title] [Unique Title Number].png`, and failing that the Slide is missing a Title, replace `[Slide Title]` with `[Placeholder Title]`, example (without brackets): `[KS4 All Temp] [20160630 20160731 Casual Dress] [1].png`.

  - The Unique Title Number should start from 1 for each slide, except where multiple slides of the exact same name are generated, then the number should increase per slide for that file name

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Const ImageBaseName As String = "Slide_"
Const ImageWidth As Long = 1920
Const ImageHeight As Long = 1080
Const ImageType As String = "PNG"

Function fileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim obj_fso As Object

    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)

End Function

Sub ExportSlides()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim Path As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim i As Long

    If ActivePresentation.Path = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please save the presentation then try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Select Path"

    Path = GetSetting("FPPT", "Export", "Default Path")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select destination folder"
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For i = 1 To .Count
            For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
                If Not oSl.Shapes.HasTitle Then
                    File = .Name(i) & ImageBaseName & Format(oSl.SlideIndex, "0000") & "." & ImageType
                    Else: File = .Name(i) & oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & Format(oSl.SlideIndex, "0000") & "." & ImageType
                End If
                If Not fileExists(Path, File) Then
                    oSl.Export Path & "\" & File, ImageType, ImageWidth, ImageHeight
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The code currently generates the files, but duplicates every slide with every section name, instead of just the slides within those sections.

Comment: You need to add some code in your loop through the slides to only process the slide if it's in `Section(i)`  Maybe test `oSl.SectionIndex` ?Some code here related to working with sections: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/PowerPoint-2010-Insert-b6f1e012

Comment: That worked pretty much perfectly, @TimWilliams. I added after the For Each oSl an If i = oSl.SectionIndex and it didn't create the duplicates. The only remaining problem is creating the unique title number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach for sequential numbering:

```
Dim dict As Object, sName As String
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")


With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
    For i = 1 To .Count
        For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

            If Not oSl.Shapes.HasTitle Then
                sName = .Name(i) & ImageBaseName
            Else
                sName = .Name(i) & oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            End If

            dict(sName) = dict(sName) + 1
            File = sName & Format(dict(sName), "0000") & "." & ImageType

            If Not fileExists(Path, File) Then
                oSl.Export Path & "\" & File, ImageType, ImageWidth, ImageHeight
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Comment: This method was almost the same as one I made myself, but yours is much cleaner, thanks Tim!

Comment: In case it helps with the numbering, each slide in a presentation will have a a unique .SlideID property.  SlideIDs begin at 256 and increment for each newly added slide, and are never duplicated. When a slide is moved within a presentation, its .SlideIndex changes, but the .SlideID remains the same.